# Changing country or region without spending the remaining apple balance from gift card

Tags: apple-id

What will happen if i change my country or region to another country without spending the remaining balance i have in my apple id which i redeemed from gift card?
Can i still buy subscription from another country using that remaining balance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t use credit from your Apple ID’s previous country’s iTunes store in its new country. Because of this, you have to fully deplete the credit on your Apple ID before [changing its country](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389) by purchasing stuff or [giving it out as a gift](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201783) to someone with an Apple ID with the same country. If the amount is too small to purchase anything or to give it out as a gift, you can [contact Apple support](https://support.apple.com/contact).